# How to set the criticality of certain test case in RIDE?

Tags: python-2.7, automated-tests, robotframework

Let's assume I want to set a test case status with (non critical) so that when the generated report which is displayed after execution excludes this test cases from its critical test cases... if i want to do that from the command line I would write ( pybot --noncritical ) but what if I want to do the same in RIDE tool ?

Answer (score 1):

In the "Run" Tab, put "--noncritical your_tags" in the "Arguments" box. That should do it.